# Unexpected behavior while iterating over JavaScript DOMTokenList

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I don't quite get how iteration over a JavaScript [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) works. I guess, this is not specific for a DOMTokenList but rather for (many?) JavaScript-Objects. As you can see in the below snippet, I want to remve all classes of a `div` by iterating over the corresponding DOMTokenList. But only function `testC()` which first collects the class names in an extra array removes all classes. Functions `testA()` and `testB()` will alwyas retain the css class `b`. Why?

Remarks: I know of course that it's possible to remove all classes of an object in a better way. However, I stumbled over this for me unexpected behavior and want to understand what I did wrong.

```js
function testA() {
  const element = document.getElementById('foo')
  const elementClassList = element.classList
  elementClassList.forEach(function(key) {
    elementClassList.remove(key)
  })
  console.log(elementClassList)
}

function testB() {
  const element = document.getElementById('bar')
  const elementClassList = element.classList
  const iterator = elementClassList.values()
  for (let value of iterator) {
    elementClassList.remove(value)
  }
  console.log(elementClassList)
}

function testC() {
  const element = document.getElementById('bat')
  const elementClassList = element.classList
  let classNames = []
  elementClassList.forEach(function(names) {
    classNames.push(names)
  })

  classNames.forEach(function(name) {
    elementClassList.remove(name)
  })

  console.log(elementClassList)
}
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px gray;
  background: #F8F9FA;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>DOMTOKenlost mystery</title>

  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main>

    <div id="foo" class="a b c">
      #Foo<br> CSS-classes: a b c
    </div>
    <div id="bar" class="a b c">
      #Bat<br> CSS-classes: a b c
    </div>
    <div id="bat" class="a b c">
      #Ba<br> CSS-classes: a b c
    </div>
    <hr>
    <button onclick="testA()" type="button">testA()</button>
    <button onclick="testB()" type="button">testB()</button>
    <button onclick="testC()" type="button">testC()</button>
  </main>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are altering the list during the loop. By altering the list you shift the indexes. Lets go over the loop in more detail:

First iteration:

- Current index: `0`
- Index of a: `0` *(matches current index)*
- Index of b: `1`
- Index of c: `2`

Second iteration:

- Current index: `1`
- Index of a: **removed**
- Index of b: `0`
- Index of c: `1` *(matches current index)*

Last iteration:

- Current index: `2`
- Index of a: **removed**
- Index of b: `0`
- Index of c: **removed**

As you can see the only items that get removed are the ones where the current index matches the elements index.

To solve this issue you can make a copy of the classList and loop over it.

```js
function testA() {
  const element = document.getElementById('foo')
  const elementClassList = [...element.classList]; // Make a copy.
  elementClassList.forEach(function(key) {
    element.classList.remove(key) // Remove from the original.
  })
  console.log(element.classList)
}
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="a b c">
  #Foo<br> CSS-classes: a b c
</div>
<hr>
<button onclick="testA()" type="button">testA()</button>
```

Comment: I thought it's something like this. Thank you! In your code snippet `console.log(element.classList)` instead of `console.log(elementClassList)` would better demonstrate your point. You might want to edit.

Comment: Yes, good point. Will make an edit.